# Locu API post request in Java

Tags: java, json, api, post, curl

```
 curl -X POST https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search -d '{"api_key" : 
 "f165c0e560d0700288c2f70cf6b26e0c2de0348f", "fields" : [ "locu_id" ], 
  "venue_queries" : [{"menus" : { "$present" : true }}]}'
```

This is an API post request and it works from the terminal. I want to make it work through a Java program. I am a beginner so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the convenient [apache components httpclient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html) to make http requests from a java program.

Comment: What should my nameValuePairs be?